# How to get file/directory owner in javascript in a platform-independent way

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, fs

I'm trying to get the SID of the owner of a file/directory in Windows using javascript.

I tried using `fs.lstatSync(p)` but it only returns the uid and the gid (only relevant to linux).

How do I get the SID if I'm on Windows ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the discussion on https://github.com/baudehlo/node-fs-ext/issues/26 indicates there is still no platform-indepent solution.